# How to extract fields from a json string using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

How to extract two fields from a JSON file using jq?

When I run 'jq '.node' out.json I get the word 'null' in output

Here is what I have in a file named out.json

```
head out.json 
{ "items": [ {"node":"aaaa-cn001.me.com","status":"success","result":{"stdout":"3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64\n","stderr":"","exit_code":0}} , {"node":"aaaa-cn002.me.com","status":"success","result":{"stdout":"3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64\n","stderr":"","exit_code":0}} , {"node":"aaaa-cn003.me.com","status":"success","result":{"stdout":"3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64\n","stderr":"","exit_code":0}} , {"node":"aaaa-cn004.me.com","status":"success","result":{"stdout":"3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64\n","stderr":"","exit_code":0}}
```

I would like the output to be this way:

```
aaaa-cn001.me.com 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64
aaaa-cn002.me.com 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
aaaa-cn003.me.com 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
aaaa-cn004.me.com 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Your input isn't JSON.  (You're missing `]}` at the end).  People answering questions are more likely to do so if they don't have to massage your sample data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you want the following :

```
jq --raw-output '.items[] | .node + " " + .result.stdout' out.json
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/CAMSFmpe3W)

Comment: Op probably wants `-r` as well.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `--raw-output` is `-r`'s long form :)

Comment: @Aaron Thank you so much!. I can't tell you how happy I am seeing the result your command produced. You nailed it!!

Answer (score 2):

if interested in an alternative solution, there's anoter way of achieving the same - using a walk-path based unix utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**:

```
bash $ <out.json jtc -w'[items][:][node]<n>v[-1][result][stdout]' -T'"{n} {}"' -qq
aaaa-cn001.me.com 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64

aaaa-cn002.me.com 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64

aaaa-cn003.me.com 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64

aaaa-cn004.me.com 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64

bash $
```

Note, an extra line occurs here, because `stdout` values carry trailing `\n`, which upon unquoting JSON string (`-qq`) results in the extra spacer.

If you like to print w/o preserving that line, use this form then:

```
bash $ <out.json jtc -w'[items][:][node]<n>v[-1][result][stdout]:<(.*)\\n>R' -T'"{n} {$1}"' -qq
aaaa-cn001.me.com 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64
aaaa-cn002.me.com 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
aaaa-cn003.me.com 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
aaaa-cn004.me.com 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64
bash $
```

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` - shell cli tool for JSON operations